# Map with int key in objectiveC

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, nsdictionary, mutable

I need to map integer values to objects in some sort of mutable array. What would be the best way to go about this. The only options I see are to use objectiveC++ ...

```
std::map<int, id> theMap;  // if i can use id?
```

or put the ints into `NSString` or `NSNumber` to use as keys for an `NSMutableDictionary`.

I am using this for my network class where the client would send some data (the key would be in the payload). Then on read the key would be extracted from the packet, then object in the map would be pulled out to continue the program based on what was received. (I was worried about the client receiving payloads out of order or lost payloads.)

Which would be the best / fastest approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option (if you don't want to mess with C++) is using a `NSMutableDictionary` with `NSNumber`s as keys. This is easier with the new literal syntax:

```
NSMutableDictionary *map = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
map[@1] = @"A value";
map[@578] = @"Another string";
int key = 310; // doesn't matter where this comes from
map[@(key)] = @"From a variable!";
```

Comment: im guessing that NSNumber *one_ns = @(one_int); is the same as alloc and init with integer one_int after compiling? - Sure looks nice tho! :)

Comment: From the [docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html): `Objects created using the literal or boxed expression syntax are not guaranteed to be uniqued by the runtime, but nor are they guaranteed to be newly-allocated`. It's like `NSString` literals.